# Python Regex to reorder parts of file name: removing a duplicate from name and spliting a group

Tags: python, regex

I'm working on trying to rename multiple files using a regex in Python (3.8), reordering the file names for consistency. The aim is for a part number description to be moved to the beginning of the file if appropriate. Not all files contain a PNo.

Some example file name structures I am working with in my testing are shown below. I've tried to capture some of the possible variations on how things may have been entered previously.

```
Test Document One PNo 6477 Rev 2
Test Document TwoPno5555 - Rev 1
Test Document 3 PNo5343 rev 2
PNo 6478 - Test Document 4 Rev1
Test Document Five Pno 3333
```

For the most part, my regex works as desired, however there are two things I'd still like to achieve:

Documents two and four have an existing hyphen and these become duplicated when combining groups to create the new file name. I've tried adding [-] into the regex, but it breaks the third group, and  I couldn't get that to work in files without a hyphen in their name. What is the best way to address this?

Second, when an existing part number does not have a space between alpha-numeric string I'd like to add it to the new file name. Can this be done using the existing python group somehow? I did consider splitting the Pno to two separate groups but thought the risk of 4 digits in other filenames (e.g.dates) would mess this up.

I'd be happy for some critique on what I've done here. This is my first attempt at writing a regex so if there's a better way, I'm all ears. Thx

```
PNoRegex = re.compile(r"""^(.*?)       
                   (PNo\s\d{4}|PNo\d{4}|Pno\s\d{4}|Pno\d{4})    # part number details
                   \s*             #remove white space after PNo string
                   (.*)$          # all text after Part No
                   """, re.VERBOSE)

for originalFile in os.listdir('.'):
    fileNameText = PNoRegex.search(originalFile)

# Skip files without a Regex match
if fileNameText == None:
    continue
# separate the groups
beforePNo   = fileNameText.group(1)
PNo         = fileNameText.group(2)
afterPNo    = fileNameText.group(3)

# Form the reordered filename.
newFileName = PNo + ' - ' + beforePNo + afterPNo
```

Edit: Screenshots added of the files.

[List of files before regex operation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tzGMH.jpg)

[After performing operation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AUCO5.jpg)

Comment: also include the final output of these files names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `re.sub`:

```
re.sub(r'(?i)^(.*?)\s*(PNo)\s*(\d{4})\s*(?:-\s*)?(.*)$', r'\2 \3 - \1 \4', string)
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/BIikWF/1).

Explanation:

```
NODE                     EXPLANATION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?i)                     set flags for this block (case-
                           insensitive) (with ^ and $ matching
                           normally) (with . not matching \n)
                           (matching whitespace and # normally)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    .*?                      any character except \n (0 or more times
                             (matching the least amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \s*                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \2:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    PNo                      'PNo'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \2
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \s*                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \3:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \d{4}                    digits (0-9) (4 times)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \3
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \s*                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture (optional
                           (matching the most amount possible)):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    -                        '-'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \s*                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0
                             or more times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )?                       end of grouping
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \4:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    .*                       any character except \n (0 or more times
                             (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \4
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  $                        before an optional \n, and the end of the
                           string
```

Answer (score 1):

You can shorten the alternation to `(P[nN]o)\s?(\d{4})` using a character class and matching an optional whitespace char.

You could use 2 capturing groups instead of 1 in case there is a space between pno and the digits.

To match the optional hyphen, you can extend matching either a whitespace char or a hyphen using a character class `[-\s]*`

This will result in separate groups for the parts in the current example data.

```
^(.*?)(P[nN]o)\s?(\d{4})[-\s]*(.*)$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/lcAtTa/1)

Comment: Thanks :) for the answer & for the link. That's a better editor than I was using. The visual clues are quite helpful. I need to work through the changes in the rest of my code to get the output, but I can see how this improved what I was working with.